# тля во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь

Устойчив к тлям - как правильно во множественном числе?

Answer (score 1):

"К тлям" используется, если имеются в виду **особи** тли:

*Пришлось приблизиться к тлям (к насекомым, к особям) для дезинфекции.*

*Если несколько тлей (особей) завелось в доме - нужно решать проблему срочно.*

*Когда тлям (особям) перестает хватать растительного сока, они начинают сосать кровь друг друга.*

Если имеется в виду **вид** насекомых, то правильнее использовать собирательное существительное "тля":

*Поражение всходов тлёй.* || Пример из gramota.ru.

*Средство от тли.* || От такого вида насекомых.

***Устойчив к тле.*** || Устойчив не к особям, а в общем - к виду насекомых.

Результаты поиска Google: "устойчив к тле" - **1410** результатов, а "устойчив к тлям" - всего лишь **6**.

Answer (score 0):

Во **множественном** числе так и правильно - *к тлям*.

Смотрите все формы здесь: **[тля](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%8F)**

Но по-русски в подобных контекстах обычно употребляют [собирательное существительное](https://goldrussian.ru/nekonkretnye-sobiratelnye-sushhestvitelnye.html) "**тля**", которое имеет форму только единственного числа. Т.е. **устойчив к тле** (*саранче, мошкаре*).

Пример:
["Устойчивость сорго к обыкновенной злаковой тле SCHIZAPHIS GRAMINUM ROND. в связи с селекцией на иммунитет"](http://earthpapers.net/ustoychivost-sorgo-k-obyknovennoy-zlakovoy-tle-schizaphis-graminum-rond-v-svyazi-s-selektsiey-na-immunitet).

**Edit**:

Поверхностный поиск в гугл даёт оба варианта употребления. Чтобы попробовать копнуть чуть глубже, нужен более полный контекст от автора вопроса.

На gramota.ru есть такой [вопрос/ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=294306) на схожую тему:

> Вопрос № 294306   Как правильно: "поражение всходов тлей" или
>   "поражение всходов тлями"?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Верен первый вариант.

Comment: *Да, пожалуй, "к тлям" встречается (в гугло-поиске) еще и чаще, чем "к тле".*  — Почему? "К тлям" - 3850 результатов, а "к тле" - 7240.

Comment: Я, кажется, вбил "устойчивость к тлям". Не помню.

Comment: "Устойчив к тле" - 1410 результатов, а "устойчив к тлям" - 6! Такое соотношение - уже весомый аргумент.

Comment: *Верен первый вариант* - сильно зависит от контекста.  Вы меня переврали, кстати. Я не говорил, что верно только "к тлям". Я говорил, что если имеется в виду некоторые виды тлей - то надо множественное.

Comment: @behemothus Автор растворился, контекста, видимо, не дождёмся. Переврал... не знаю, я лишь написал, что вы с ответом не согласны. Могу убрать эту строчку, она, в общем-то, ни к чему.

Answer (score 0):

Множественное число от тля вы использовали верно, оно не вызывает трудности при образовании и склонении.

Судя по всему, ваш вопрос как раз и касался необходимости использования множественного числа. Я не согласен с тем, что здесь надо использовать "собирательное" единственное. Дело в том, что такое прием годится для бытового применения, но в более научном стиле имеется в виду не просто множественное, а разные виды объекта ("бензины" - разные сорта или марки бензина, "минеральные воды", "философии Востока" - и проч.).

В нашем случае "тли" - обширное надсемейство, в которое входит много видов. Причем не все из них являются вредителями культупных растений. В этой ситуации использование "к тлям" вполне логично.

Comment: В вопросе контекста нет. Тем не менее специалисты (насколько я могу судить, не будучи таким специалистом) предпочитают *к тле*, *к различным видам тли*. *К тлям* - не звучит. Добавил пример в ответ. Хотя... и так, и так встречается.